# Problem with installment of Common Lisp requirements

Tags: emacs, require

I am trying to learn common lisp and following the installation process from https://lisp-lang.org/learn/getting-started/

The website says to add something to my ~/.emacs file, but I do not find it. Does someone now where I can find that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtJLt.png)

Comment: Is the directory of that Lisp file in your `load-path`? If not, use `add-to-list` to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to install a custom `slime` to use `Common Lisp` on `Linux`. Maybe one should install it from a given distribution, it would be easier.

I would suggest the following steps:

**1. Setup `Emacs` to use [`MELPA repository`](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started):**

`M-x customize-variable`

`Customize Variable: package-archives`

Then, simply add `melpa` with the URL `https://melpa.org/packages`

Then press the button `Apply and Save`.

**2. Install `slime` from the `package manager`**

`M-x list-packages`

Search for `slime`, press `i` for install and then press `x` to proceed. You should have a proper version of `slime` installed.

**3. Happily hack `Common Lisp`!**

EDIT:

I missed this [installation method](https://lisp-lang.org/learn/getting-started/#:%7E:text=SLIME%20is%20a%20Common%20Lisp%20IDE%20built%20on,%3Aquicklisp-slime-helper%29%27%20--quit%20Then%2C%20add%20this%20to%20your%20%7E%2F.emacs.d%2Finit.el%3A) that you probably followed. In this case, I believe that the `init` directory has a typo and is missing a dot (`.`)

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
                           ^
                           \---- HERE
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for your answer. How can I fix the typo and where? I am new to LISP, excuse my lack of knowledge

Comment: I think that your issue is not related to LISP, it is related to the Emacs/Slime installation and configuration. I provided the answer based on the error message you provided, you might be able to edit the file `~/.emacs`. If you want better answers, I suggest to provide more details: Linux or Windows, which Emacs distribution, which steps did you follow to install `slime` or which tutorial did you read. I suggest you to edit your question and add more details.

Comment: I am using linux ubuntu and followed the steps from the website which I added to the question thanks to your suggestion. Thank you for trying to help, I still did not manage to solve problem and can therefore unfortunately not continue learning common lisp.